# Foursquare - Venue Claim

Tags: foursquare

We're working on uploading businesses to Foursquare via the API option. We ran a test and have a question but first, here's some background on our situation:

We managed to get venues/add working however, we had issues with venues/claim.

When we attempted to claim a clinic which already existed on [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/v/harborview-adult-medicine-clinic/4e4bcf61483bb8f0599687a4), 
we received the response code 403 and the following details:

> {meta={code=403, errorType=not_authorized,
>   requestId=59416bb6db04f547b5e4b8a5, errorDetail=not authorized to
>   claim via api}, response={}, notifications=[{item={unreadCount=0},
>   type=notificationTray}]}

The API documentation indicates that the user performing this API call “Must be venue manager”. We don’t know whether our account is a venue manager and foursquare hasn't been too helpful in telling us if it is or isn't.

Can anyone please let us know how can we become a venue manager?

We are going to have approximately 2,000 locations uploaded via API and of that amount, we anticipate existing clinics to be a reoccurring theme so any insights in making this an efficient process would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Venue claims are generally not available via API.  Business owners will usually go through this page (https://foursquare.com/venue/claim) to claim their business.

If you're interested in claiming via API, please send us a note at api@foursquare.com!